# CSS3 box-shadow for overlapping-like divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve this effect with css3:

[image: header/main]

The HTML code is cleanly something like

```
...
<header>
    ...
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
    ...
</div>
...
```

and the css is, for the moment, something like

```
header {
    display: block;
    width: 900px;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #211C18;
    ...
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 820px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    ...
    border-right: 1px solid #211C18;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #211C18;
    border-left: 1px solid #211C18;
    ...
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
}
```

In order to obtain the desired result, I need to:

1. Hide the top shadow of the main div *(no problem with that)*
2. Bring header's bottom shadow in front of the main div, and not behind as it is right now.

I've been reading a lot about box-shadow, and I haven't found a solution that really pleases me...
Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVWF8/1/) does what you want.

The way it works is with a main `#wrap` element that centres the content and creates a coordinate map for the absolutely positioned `#main` element.  It does this because of its position: relative CSS rule.  You end up with the following markup:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <header></header>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

The `header` is then placed inside of this and given position: relative and a z-index to set it stacking above the `#main` container.

Finally `#main` is absolutely positioned below the `header`.  The CSS looks like so:

```
/* centre content and create coordinate map for absolutely positioned #main */
#wrap {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

header, #main {
    background: #fff;

    /* rounded corners */
    border: 1px solid #211C18;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;    

    /* dropshadows */
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 20px #005377;
}

header {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;

    /* stack above the #main container */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;

    /* stack below the header and underlap it...if that's even a word */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 40px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was very detailed and useful...
But... what if I have a footer and #main height isn't fixed (it can change A LOT according to page's content)? Adding absolute positions  to the layout will move it upwards...

Comment: If your `header` is fixed height, then you can just swap the CSS around and make the header position absolute and have it overlap the position relative `#main`.

Comment: Oh... looks that the problem is that the wrap collapses, so that it doesn't span for all the contained divs height, like in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pbx4L/1/ [Thank you so much Pat for making me know jsfiddle] I used to deal with collapsing parents while using floats, but in this case I don't know how to fix the problem...

Comment: Here's a simplified version that doesn't use absolute positioning nor a wrapping element (the only thing you really needed to change was to give `header` a higher `z-index` than `main`: http://jsfiddle.net/DVWF8/199/

Answer (score 3):

I just had some luck using relative positioning.

For example.

1st div has a box-shadow, and a bottom margin.  2nd div slides up under the shadow.

```
#firstdiv {width: 960px; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc; margin-bottom: 10px;}
#seconddiv {width: 960px; position: relative; top: -10px;}
```

It's not the best solution but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

setting position to "relative" will already solve the problem!