# My box-shadow is being covered by an image

Tags: html, css

If you look here at http://jsfiddle.net/nqugcutn/ you'll notice that the box-shadow on my header is being covered by the content, which has a background of an image. (Pardon the missing font). How can I get the box-shadow to appear?

```
/* Header */

.header {
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 75px;
    border-top: 5px solid #1379DB;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    z-index: 1;
}

.logoName {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    float: left;
}

/* Content */

.container {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ScGxG2b.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #242424;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your z-index on container is higher than the z-index on the header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 box-shadow for overlapping-like divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410727/css3-box-shadow-for-overlapping-like-divs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `position: relative;` to your `.header` div will make the box-shadow appear above the background image. Here's a demo:

```css
/* Header */

.header {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 75px;
  border-top: 5px solid #1379DB;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.logoName {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  float: left;
}
.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 250px;
  float: right;
}
.header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.header ul li a {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.header ul li a:hover,
.header ul li a:active {
  border-bottom: #1379DB solid;
  color: #000;
}
.header ul li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Content */

.container {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ScGxG2b.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #242424;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="logoName">Company Name</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/showcase">Showcase</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/message">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqugcutn/2/)**.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Out of curiosity just in case of a change, let's say I wanted to make it scroll with the page though. Would I have to use JavaScript for that, or is there an alternative?

Comment: You can simply use `position: fixed` instead of `position: relative` in that case. Here's a demo for that: http://jsfiddle.net/nqugcutn/3/

Comment: to make it stay in position regardless of scrolling, use position:fixed.

Comment: Oh, it would still keep it fixed? Guess I should have tested it first :$ Thank you though!